# url not rewriting i am using below code and mod_rewrite is also on

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-routing

My url is like:

> http://www.example.com/mock_profile.php?user_name=Yasin

but I want an seo friendly url like:

> http://www.example.com/Yasin

I am using the below url RewriteRule in my httaccess but it is not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ mock_profile.php?user_name=Yasin  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ mock_profile.php?user_name=Yasin



## Below is my all httacess code ##
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [NC,L,R=301]


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ mock_profile.php?user_name=$1
```

Comment: i didn't get any right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ mock_profile.php?user_name=$1 [L]
```

Explaination:

The following Condition tells the server to stop rewriting if the Request is for an existing directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And this tells the server to stop rewriting if the request is for a valid file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If the request is not for a file /dir ,then rewrite it :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ mock_profile.php?user_name=$1
```

Comment: dear Starkeen i used your code but still not working  please help me . i paste all my httaccess code here..

Comment: Can you post it in your question?

Comment: i do every thing but still i not getting solution's you sell all httacces code in above question

Comment: I saw your htaccess file, but why are you redirecting .html to .php and .php to .html?

Comment: i am only .php redirecting to .html

Comment: i am removing all code only your code put in httaccess but same problem not rewrite url what's the problem???..

Comment: Is your htaccess in root folder? and what is the url you entered in browser?

Comment: i am working on localhost and httaccess in my root folder  my url is        -> "http://at4/group_on1/mock_profile.html?user_name=Yasin"

Comment: Ok I edited the answer, I added a "RewriteBase /" , try the updated

Comment: Now you can enter http://www.example.com/username it will internally redirect to your old url.

Comment: my url is http://at4/group_on1/mock_profile.php?user_name=Yasin     but i want to rewrite url and after url rewrite url look like  -> http://at4/group_on1/Yasin what i should do???